# Is it possible to configure clang-format to keep Java lambda arguments on one line with arrow and curly brace?

Tags: java, clang-format

My `clang-format` style file is the following:

```
BasedOnStyle: Google
---
Language: Java
ColumnLimit: 100
BreakStringLiterals: true
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  true
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  IndentBraces:    true
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
```

Consider the following input java code:

```
public class Lambda {
  void handle() {

    // TODO Try a compiling example next to see if it's different with clang-format.
    try {
      updateTranscriptResponse = Utils.doWithRetry(
        /* task */
        () -> {
        System.out.println("This is a bit long-winded sentence so it keeps going on and on.");
        System.out.println("This is a bit long-winded sentence so it keeps going on and on.");
        },
        /* task 2 */
        () -> {
        System.out.println("This is a bit long-winded sentence so it keeps going on and on and on and on and on.");
        System.out.println("This is a bit long-winded sentence so it keeps going on and on.");
        },
        /* task 3 */
        () -> {
        System.out.println("This is a bit long-winded sentence so it keeps going on and on and on and on and on.");
        System.out.println("This is a bit long-winded sentence so it keeps going on and on.");
        }
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to get `clang-format` to indent the body of the lambdas but keep `() -> {` on a single line. Unfortunately, it gives me the following output:

```
public class Lambda {
  void handle() {
    // TODO Try a compiling example next to see if it's different with clang-format.
    try {
      updateTranscriptResponse = Utils.doWithRetry(
          /* task */
          ()
              -> {
            System.out.println("This is a bit long-winded sentence so it keeps going on and on.");
            System.out.println("This is a bit long-winded sentence so it keeps going on and on.");
          },
          /* task 2 */
          ()
              -> {
            System.out.println(
                "This is a bit long-winded sentence so it keeps going on and on and on and on and on.");
            System.out.println("This is a bit long-winded sentence so it keeps going on and on.");
          },
          /* task 3 */
          () -> {
            System.out.println(
                "This is a bit long-winded sentence so it keeps going on and on and on and on and on.");
            System.out.println("This is a bit long-winded sentence so it keeps going on and on.");
          });
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}
```

How can I configure `clang-format` to not introduce the extra line breaks at Task 1 and Task 2?

I'm running clang-format 9.